# jquery mobile - implementing history navigation on dynamic pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation, history

I have a mobile app im making on jqm.

It consists of one page that is dynamically updated with new content when a link is clicked. Url parsing and logic happens in the `$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange")`. What I want to do is to have custom history back, refresh, forward etc. I have added the history class below and what is happening. I basically save the function that brings in the new content in a stack and call it when back, refresh is clicked.

I am having problems explaining question so im going to put a link to the app and you can see what happens when you click the list view and try to click the back button
[Mobile App](http://www.veepiz.com/3.4.0)

As you can see when back is clicked, everything on the page vanishes. How can I implement custom history in jqm?

```js
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) { 
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
        re = /^#wallmsg_page/;
        re1 = /^#public_post_page/;
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        var $page = $( '#index_page' );
        if ( u.hash.search(re) !== -1 ) {

            window.nHistory.add(function ()
            {
                var edata=data;
                var eu=u;
                var $epage=$page;
                console.log(data.toPage);
                showPublicPost( eu, edata.options );
                $epage.page();
                edata.options.dataUrl = eu.href;
                edata.options.transition = 'flip';
                $.mobile.changePage( $epage, edata.options );                        
            });
            window.nHistory.getStack()[(window.nHistory.getStack().length-1)]();
            e.preventDefault();
        } else
            if ( u.hash.search(re1) !== -1 ) {
            var edata=data;
            window.nHistory.add(function ()
            {                
                var edata=data;
                var eu=u;
                var $epage=$page;

                showNextPage(eu,edata.options);
                $epage.page();
                edata.options.dataUrl = eu.href;
                edata.options.transition = 'flip';
                $.mobile.changePage( $epage, edata.options );                        
            });
            window.nHistory.getStack()[(window.nHistory.getStack().length-1)]();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        //console.log(window.nHistory.getStack());
    }
});

//implement history
var Stack = function () {
    var stack = [];
    this.add = function (cFunc) {
        stack.push(cFunc);
        return this;
    };
    this.get = function () {
        return stack.pop();
    };
    this.size = function () {
        return stack.length;
    };
    this.isEmpty = function () {
        return (stack.length == 0);
    };
    this.getStack = function () {
        return stack;
    };
};
window.nHistory = new Stack();
var moveBack = function () {
    if (!(window.nHistory.isEmpty())) {
        var c = window.nHistory.get();
        c();
    } else {
        goHome();
    }
}
var refreshPage = function () {
    window.nHistory.getStack()[(window.nHistory.getStack().length-1)]();
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the JQM history instead? I tried setting up my own history for a project, too. Eventually I decided it's just easier to work within the framework. If you check the JQM source code (about line 2800) you can see you have functions to make own history entries and to retrieve these as well.